# S3 VPC end point Bucket policy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have multiple EC2 instances originating form a single VPC and i want to assign a bucket policy to my s3 to make sure that only that VPC traffic will be allowed to access the bucket so i created an end point for  that VPC and it added all the policies and routes in routing table. I assigned a following policy to my bucket

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909153",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringtEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-111bbb22"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

but it does not work when i connect to my Bucket using AWS-SDK for nodejs i get access denied error. The nodejs application is actually running in the Ec2 instance launched in same VPC as end point.

I even tried VPC level bucket policy but still i get access denied error. Can anyone tell me if i need to include any endpoint parameter in SDK S3 connection or any other thing?

Comment: Did you [configure the Route Table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html) to point to the VPC-Endpoint?

Comment: Did you leave the default endpoint policy intact, or have you modified it? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html#vpc-endpoints-access

Comment: I did not updated the Endpoint policy. MY Application is using AWS SDK in an Ec2 instance that is under same VPC to which endpoint is assigned. When i launched it, it populated the routing table automatically so what changes i need to do there in order for it to successfully connect to the S3 bucket with my above policy?